# Query returns ids specified in NOT IN case

Tags: mysql

The following query still returns the value 10643 even though it's specifically listed in the NOT IN condition.

```
    SELECT 
    `media` . `id`
   FROM 
    `media`
   LEFT JOIN 
    `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `media`.`category_id`
   JOIN 
    `users` ON `users`.`id` = `media`.`author`
   WHERE 
    `media`.`public` =1
   AND 
    `media`.`date_posted` <= (SELECT CONVERT_TZ(now(),'US/Pacific','US/Eastern'))
   AND 
    `media`.`date_posted` > DATE_SUB((SELECT CONVERT_TZ(now(),'US/Pacific','US/Eastern')) , INTERVAL 25 DAY )
   AND
    `media`.`id` NOT IN ('10659,10656,10655,10654,10653,10652,10651,10650,10649,10648,10646,10647,10645,10644,10643')
   ORDER BY 
   `media`.`views` DESC
   LIMIT 15
```

**Tables**

**Categories**
id | category

**Media**
id | type | category_id | title | subtitle | author | image | content | public | date_posted | views

**Users**
id | firstname | lastname

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax for NOT IN () is incorrect. You were giving it a single string, do it like this instead:

```
SELECT 
`media` . `id`
FROM 
`media`
LEFT JOIN 
`categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `media`.`category_id`
JOIN 
`users` ON `users`.`id` = `media`.`author`
WHERE 
`media`.`public` =1
AND 
`media`.`date_posted` <= (SELECT CONVERT_TZ(now(),'US/Pacific','US/Eastern'))
AND 
`media`.`date_posted` > DATE_SUB((SELECT CONVERT_TZ(now(),'US/Pacific','US/Eastern')) ,     INTERVAL 25 DAY )
 AND
`media`.`id` NOT IN ('10659', '10656' , '10655', '10654', '10653', '10652', '10651', '10650', '10649', '10648', '10646', '10647', '10645', '10644', '10643')
ORDER BY 
`media`.`views` DESC
LIMIT 15
```

Answer (score 1):

You have quotations around the numbers 
Try NOT IN (10659, 10660 ...)

Comment: Can't believe i missed something so simple. Thank you!

Comment: It happens, I've spend long periods of time digging through code only to realize I missed something simple.